# Modifying list of dictionary using list comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have the following list of dictionary

```
myList = [{'one':1, 'two':2,'three':3},
          {'one':4, 'two':5,'three':6},
          {'one':7, 'two':8,'three':9}]
```

This is just an example of a dictionary that I have. My question is, it possible to somehow modify say key `two` in all the dictionary to become twice their value, **using list comprehension ?**

I know how to use list comprehension to create new list of dictionary, but don't know how to modify them, I have come up with something like this

```
new_list = { <some if condiftion> for (k,v) in x.iteritems() for x in myList  }
```

I am not sure how to specify a condition in the `<some if condiftion>`, also is the nested list comprehension format I am thinking of correct ?

I want the final output as per my example like this

```
[ {'one':1, 'two':4,'three':3},{'one':4, 'two':10,'three':6},{'one':7, 'two':16,'three':9}  ]
```

Comment: List comprehension is used to build *new* lists, not modify old ones.

Comment: What you created is a dictionary comprehension, not a list comprehension. Well, so far as `{` and `[` are concerned

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use list comprehension with nested dict comprehension:

```
new_list = [{ k: v * 2 if k == 'two' else v for k,v in x.items()} for x in myList]
print (new_list)
[{'one': 1, 'two': 4, 'three': 3}, 
 {'one': 4, 'two': 10, 'three': 6}, 
 {'one': 7, 'two': 16, 'three': 9}]
```

Answer (score 3):

In python 3.5+ you can use the new unpacking syntax in dict literals introduced in [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/). This creates a copy of each dict and then overwrites the value for the key `two`:

```
new_list = [{**d, 'two': d['two']*2} for d in myList]
# result:
# [{'one': 1, 'two': 4, 'three': 3},
#  {'one': 4, 'two': 10, 'three': 6},
#  {'one': 7, 'two': 16, 'three': 9}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myList = [ {'one':1, 'two':2,'three':3},{'one':4, 'two':5,'three':6},{'one':7, 'two':8,'three':9}  ]

[ { k: 2*i[k] if k == 'two' else i[k] for k in i } for i in myList ]

[{'one': 1, 'three': 3, 'two': 4}, {'one': 4, 'three': 6, 'two': 10}, {'one': 7, 'three': 9, 'two': 16}]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `for` loop should be sufficient. However, if you want to use a dictionary comprehension, I find defining a mapping dictionary more readable and extendable than ternary statements:

```
factor = {'two': 2}

res = [{k: v*factor.get(k, 1) for k, v in d.items()} for d in myList]

print(res)

[{'one': 1, 'two': 4, 'three': 3},
 {'one': 4, 'two': 10, 'three': 6},
 {'one': 7, 'two': 16, 'three': 9}]
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't knew we could use mapping like this!

Comment: @MohammedKashif, Yep, the main point is for one condition an `if` / `else` ternary is fine. But it will become (more) unreadable if you have further conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Hello did you tried this :

```
for d in myList:
  d.update((k, v*2) for k, v in d.iteritems() if k == "two")
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not use `d['two'] = d['two'] * 2` instead of that `d.update(...)` thing?